# Ember PUT request using JSON is giving a weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, transactions, put

(If the next is too much to read for you, please read the last line). I'm using Ember and Rails backend from a while, but I'm still a bit stick with transactions or what other way is used to send actions to the backend. I have `Users` and `Events`. My `Users` can participate in one or several `Events`, and for each `Event` several `Users` can attend. I'm maintaining this relationship using the Mongoid macro `has_and_belongs_to_many` in this way:

**Event**

```
# ...
has_and_belongs_to_many :attendings, class_name: "User" , inverse_of: :attendances
# ...
```

**User**

```
# ...
has_and_belongs_to_many :attendances, class_name: "Event" , inverse_of: :attendings
# ...
```

In my template I'm showing a list of all the `Events` stored in my backend and a button "Attend" if the `User` is not already attending, and "Not attend" it the `User` is attending. For attending, I've tried to make the PUT request using transactions, making the next steps in my Ember Event controller:

**Event controller (Ember), `actionAttending` method using transactions:**

```
actionAttending: function() {
    var userId = this.get('controllers.app.model.id');

    this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();

    this.get('attendings').pushObject(App.User.find(userId));

    this.transaction.add(this.get('model'));
    this.transaction.commit();
}
```

When I try this, my `Event` JSON request is containing all the parameters and relations but `attendings` attribute. So I decided to try using a jQuery request:

**Event controller (Ember), actionAttending method using jQuery ajax:**

```
// ...

var eId = this.get('id');
this.get('attendings').pushObject(App.User.find(userId));
var eAttendings = this.get('attendings');

var url = "/events/" + eId + ".json";

var data = { event: { id: eId, attendings: eAttendings } };

$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: "JSON"
});
// ...
```

Well, this is pretty much working, except for the line where I declare `eAttendings`, where Ember complains about `init` function is not called, or somehing similar. After googling a bit I found a "solution", which is convert to array, so the line changed like this:

```
var eAttendings = this.get('attendings').toArray();
```

My nice error now is:

```
TypeError: fullName is undefined
var nameParts = fullName.split(":"),
```

This is raised in Firebug before my ajax request is launched. I don't know what's the exact meaning or how to fix it...

Anyway, I wanted to try if my ajax request is working, so I tried it in curl:

```
curl --request PUT localhost:3000/events/521b97ef5ef9095ba211bf70 --data "id=521b97ef5ef9095ba211bf70&attendings=521b7eda99027121d1533015"
```

The answer is:

```
{"errors":{"attendings":["is invalid"]}}
```

And the bakend is returning a `422 Unproccesable entity` answer... I've got no validations on my model on this field, so I don't know what's going on here either... My update action on Rails Event controller is like this:

```
  def update
    e = Event.find(params[:id])
    u = User.find(params[:attendings])

    if params[:attendings]
      e.attendings << u
      e.save
      respond_with e, api_template: :general_event, status: :no_content
    end   end
```

Last detail: I'm using Ember 1.0.0.rc6, jQuery 1.10.2 and gems `acts_as_api` and `active_model_serializers` in Rails.

So, to summarize, I want to get working just **my PUT request in Ember to add Users attending to an Event through the `has_many_and_belongs_to` macro** (using transactions, jQuery, or something else)

Comment: Do you try to split out a `nameParts` variable anywhere in your code?  Can you post that part?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your answer. The thing is this error caused by a lack of `nameParts` is caused by Ember.js. The function is `parseName`, in line 28288 in Ember 1.0.0-rc6. The comments say that this function "_converts the string name of the form "type:name" to a Javascript object with the parsed aspects of the name broken out_". I'm sure that a patch to pass this function can be done, but the cleanest way would be to understand why this error is happening or at least solve it... =\